# how to add a delay to .on('click', function()

Tags: javascript

i want to have text appear inside a div after a delayed period of time after a diferent div was clicked

my relevant javascript:
    $('.con').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('letter');
    })
    $('.con').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('span.letter').text('new text');
my relevant css:

```
.con {
position: absolute;
height: 100px; width:100px;
z-index: 1;
top: 350px;
Left: 320px;
}
.con.letter span.letter{
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
animation-name: introanim;
animation-duration: 7s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
position:absolute ;
top:-300px;
right: 200px;
left: -200px;
z-index: 3;
}
```

my relevant html:

```
<div class="con">
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="line"></span>
<span class="box"></span>
<center>
<span class="letter"></span>
</div>
```

i have most of it worked out except for the delay. please help!

Comment: Considered using setTimeout?

Comment: could you give me an example of that in my javascript code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time delay on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386944/time-delay-on-click)

Comment: its not a duplicate of that, im not using a button, im using a css div to be clicked on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a delay with the setTimeout function :

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#someid').addClass("done");
  //Here add what you need
}, 2000);
```

Or check the .delay function of jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: how would i use the .delay function ive tried $('.con').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('span.letter').text('new text');
})

Comment: with .delay(800) after .text and before ('new text');

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
$('.con').on('click', function(){
     window.setTimeout((function(){
       $(this).find('span.letter').text('new text');
     }).bind(this), 10);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout callback, ex.:

```
$('.con').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        method_here()
    }, delay);
}
```

see too:

[callBack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks)

[setTimeOut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: how do you set the length of the delay?

Comment: $('.con').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).find('span.letter').text('new text');
      }, delay);
})

Comment: delay is a variable that you probably don't have. Change delay at the end of the function to whatever milliseconds you like. Try 3000

Comment: i cant seem to get it to work, if you go to http://codepen.io/TechTime/pen/RGJVoR

Comment: you can find my code, and if you click change view and then full screen you can see the result in full screen, would you mind having a look at it and fixing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a timeout,

Can you try this :

```
$('.con').on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function {
    $(this).find('span.letter').text('new text');
  }, 2000);
});
```